# Make a text string fill a rectangle

Tags: image, wolfram-mathematica

Suppose I want a string, say "123", to fill a given rectangle, like so:

```
Show[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], 
     Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], Yellow, Rectangle[{.1, .5}, {.4, .9}]}], 
     Graphics[Text[Style["123", Red, Bold, 67], {.1, .5}, {-1, -1}]]]
```

[image: a string in a rectangle]

But I hand-tuned the font size there (67) so that it would fill up the rectangle.
How would you make an arbitrary string fill up an arbitrary rectangle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that this is a known difficult problem.  The best answer I could find [is from John Fultz.](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Jun/msg00307.html)

```
TextRect[text_, {{left_, bottom_}, {right_, top_}}] := 
 Inset[
  Pane[text, {Scaled[1], Scaled[1]},
   ImageSizeAction -> "ResizeToFit", Alignment -> Center],
  {left, bottom}, {Left, Bottom}, {right - left, top - bottom}]

Show[
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}],
 Graphics[{
   {EdgeForm[Thick], Yellow, Rectangle[{.1, .5}, {.4, .9}]},
   TextRect[Style["123", Red, Bold], {{.1, .5}, {.4, .9}}]
 }]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice approach. BTW, the text will center vertically if you use `Scaled[1]` instead of `{Scaled[1], Scaled[1]}`.

Comment: @David thank you.  I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't work on my system. :-/

Comment: Adding the Pane option Alignment -> Center will centre the text.

Comment: Thanks so much! This looks perfect. @David, I also tried your idea and it worked for "123" but shorter strings would end up too tall. Looks like Chris's Alignment->Center is the more robust way to do it. Thanks again!

Comment: It is interesting that the text in the image from Chris's machine is not as well fit as from mine, which shows that this method does have its limitations, as indicated by John Fultz himself.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternate approach that converts the text to a texture that gets mapped to a polygon.  This has the feature of stretching the text to fit the region (since it's not really text anymore.)

```
Show[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], 
   Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], Yellow, Rectangle[{.1, .5}, {.4, .9}]}], 
   Graphics[{Texture[ImageData[
      Rasterize[Style["123", Red, Bold], "Image", RasterSize -> 300, 
         Background -> None]]], 
      Polygon[{{0.1, 0.5}, {0.4, 0.5}, {0.4, 0.9}, {0.1, 0.9}}, 
         VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As a function for easier comparison:

```
(* Render string/style s to fill a rectangle with left/bottom corner {l,b} and 
   right/top corner {r,t}. *)
textrect[s_, {{l_,b_},{r_,t_}}] := Graphics[{
  Texture[ImageData[Rasterize[s, "Image", RasterSize->300, Background->None]]], 
  Polygon[{{l,b}, {r,b}, {r,t}, {l,t}}, 
          VertexTextureCoordinates->{{0,0},{1,0},{1,1},{0,1}}]}]
```

Comment: Ooh, I like the idea of stretching it to fully fill the rectangle. But it looks grainy when I try this. I tried playing with the RasterSize parameter to no avail. I'll keep trying. Thanks Brett!

Comment: I don't quite understand why it doesn't work if you omit `ImageData`.  Also, it seems `"Image"` can be changed to `"Data"` (and then omit `ImageData`).

Comment: @Szabolcs I hadn't considered using `"Data"`.  For some reason the `Background -> None` doesn't work correctly otherwise when it's included in a texture.  (I had to ask another developer the first time I created something like this using `Texture`.)

Answer (score 1):

The suggested solution didn't work when the Plot wasn't there, I used the PlotRange option to solve it. I wrapped it in a function; Opacity, text color, etc; should be made into options;

```
textBox[text_, color_, position_: {0, 0}, width_: 2, height_: 1] := 
  Graphics[{
    {
     color, Opacity[.1],
     Rectangle[position, position + {width, height}, 
      RoundingRadius -> 0.1]
     }
    ,
    Inset[
     Pane[text, {Scaled[1], Scaled[1]}, 
      ImageSizeAction -> "ResizeToFit", Alignment -> Center], 
     position, {Left, Bottom}, {width, height}]
    }, PlotRange -> 
    Transpose[{position, position + {width, height}}]];
```